# Is it possible to make a webpage the minimum height of the viewport?

Tags: css

I have some webpages that do not reach the bottom of my browser viewport. It's particularly annoying because the footer is full width, so it hovers.

What i want to do is place the footer at least at the bottom of the viewport. I do not want to fix it as per the sticky footer solutions.

To make it more difficult, the footer is variable height.

Is it possible either via css/javascript for fixed height/variable height scenarios?

Comment: You can achieve this with javascript/jQuery, not sure about css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x=$(window).height(); 
$('.content').css('min-height',x+'px');
```

Help it works